# Как получить access token в Instagram?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, instagram

Как из WPF приложения получить access token в Instagram?

Есть много примеров, но они на ASP.NET, где при запросе вы получаете access token в Callback.

Пытался через WebClient, но постоянно выходит ошибка 403 или просто ничего не возвращается.

[Вот тут лазял](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061311/how-do-i-sucessfully-login-to-instagram-by-httprequest-in-c-sharp-net?rq=1) и [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026230/login-to-instagram-programatically) [тут](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/how-to-authenticate-and-get-data-using-instagram-api/), но все бестолку.
Уже третий день бюсь над этой задачей.

```
// Ссылка для получния access token
        var link = string.Format("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&response_type=token", ClientId, RedirectUri);

        var client = new CookieAwareWebClient();

        // Делаем запрос для получения access token
        var result = client.DownloadData(link); // тут возврощаеться страница для авторизации
        var loginLink = client.RequestUri.ToString(); // а это ссылка для авторизации
        var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);

        // Берем csr токен
        const string pattern = @"csrfmiddlewaretoken""\svalue=""(.+)""";
        var r = new Regex(pattern);
        var m = r.Match(html);
        var csr = m.Groups[1].Value;

        // Задаем параметры для последуйщей авторизации.
        var parameters = new NameValueCollection();
        parameters["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = csr;
        parameters["username"] = UserName;
        parameters["password"] = Passsword;

        // Логинимся по указанному узлу            
        var result2 = client.UploadValues(loginLink, "POST", parameters);

        if (client.RequestUri.ToString().Contains("access_token"))
            MessageBox.Show("Авторизация прошла успешна.");
```